# Listing all WMI classes with winrm/wsman

Tags: windows, dell, wmi, winrm

Is there a way to pull all WMI information from a system with a single winrm command? I can run commands such as winrm enum wmicimv2/win32_computersystem, which will give me information like:

```
Win32_ComputerSystem
    AdminPasswordStatus = 3
    AutomaticManagedPagefile = true
    AutomaticResetBootOption = true
    AutomaticResetCapability = true
    BootOptionOnLimit = null
    BootOptionOnWatchDog = null
    BootROMSupported = true
    BootupState = Normal boot
    ...
```

but is there a way to get a list of all WMI classes besides running something like get-wmiobject -list beforehand? It would also help for compiling a list of stuff to monitor on Dell's lifecycle controllers, since I can't seem to find a list of CIM classes for those.